# How to return a word from between nth comma and n+1 th comma?

Tags: excel, vba, text, extract

I want to extract a word from text which is separated by commas.

This is one of the data from users.

> 117573,117573,219,219,75,75,Messi,barcelona,53780217,forward,froquen@gmail.com

I want to get "Messi" from the data.

I can use the "text to columns" function but our data is dynamic and whenever I export it, I have to do that again and again.

I tried "MID, FIND" text formulas but in the next updates, the number of commas will change.

I am looking to a VBA code as:

Function_name(A2;6;7) => RETURN "Messi"

6= starting comma
7= the comma after the word

Comment: What version do you have, if later than 2013 and on a PC then you can use FILTERXML:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml

Comment: You can use `Split(cellValue,",")` to get a zero-based array of values, from which you could pick the (eg) 6th one using `arr(5)` (first value is `arr(0)`)

Comment: Thank you so much, according to directed question find a solution what I am looking for.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you so much, according to your tip, I found the correct search. Turning into an array is so brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

Found code from https://trumpexcel.com/vba-split-function/

```vb
Function ReturnNthElement(CellRef As Range, ElementNumber As Integer)
Dim Result() As String
Result = Split(CellRef, ",")
ReturnNthElement = Result(ElementNumber - 1)
End Function
```